# How to customize TextField to have option to either have Leading Icon or not in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a requirement where I want to give the option to add a leading icon in the TextFiled based on input parameter like this

```
@Composable
fun CustomTextFiled(iconRequired:Boolean) {

    TextField(
        value = "username",
        onValueChange = {},
        leadingIcon = {
            if(iconRequired){
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search, contentDescription = "")
            }

        }
    )
}
```

The output of above when iconRequired is true :
[image: iconRequired =true]

The output of above when iconRequired is false :
[image: iconRequired =fasle]

As it is clear when iconRequired is false, leading icon is not visible but the icon placeholder space is still there.
Is there any way , the TextFiled value "username" can start from the beginning when leadingIcon is not required i.e iconRequired = false?

I understand I can create two differnet TextFileds based on  iconRequired value, but I am looking for a way where I can achieve this without creating two different TextFields.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass `null` when you don't want to show icon, but you're passing an empty composable now. This should work:

```
TextField(
    leadingIcon = if (iconRequired) {
        {
          Icon(...)
        }
    } else null
)
```